# Laravel showing constructer as an Object Attribute

Tags: php, laravel

I'm constructing an object in the constructor, why it's appearing as an attribute.But I can call functions from it.

```
 public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    if (isset(self::$_hidden)){
        $this->hidden = self::$_hidden;
    }
    $this->mapper = new CustomFieldsMapper();
}
```

`mapper` is appended to my object as an attribute. This happens on Basemodel.How to prevent this?

Comment: by not assigning ?? please try to rephrase your question as it is not clear what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  remove the `$this->mapper = new CustomFieldsMapper();` and build object on demand.
Reson is Laravel Magic function read it as a new attribute of the model.